# finding the farthest node using Neo4j (node without any incoming relation)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have created a graph db in Neo4j and want to use it for generalization purposes.

There are about 500,000 nodes (20 distinct labels) and 2.5 million relations (50 distinct types) between them.

In an example path : a -> b -> c-> d -> e

I want to find out the node without any incoming relations (which is 'a').
And I should do this for all the nodes (finding the nodes at the beginning of all possible paths that have no incoming relations).

I have tried several Cypher codes without any success:

```
match (a:type_A)-[r:is_a]->(b:type_A) 
with a,count (r) as count
where count = 0 
set a.isFirst = 'true'
```

or

```
match (a:type_A), (b:type_A) 
where not (a)<-[:is_a*..]-(b) 
set a.isFirst = 'true'
```

Where is the problem?!

Also, I have to create this code in neo4jClient, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "without any success"? What happened?

Comment: only 10% of the nodes have no incoming relations. But my queries return all the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all nodes that have no incoming relationships, you can find them using `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
START n=node(*)
OPTIONAL MATCH n<-[r]-()
WITH n,r
WHERE r IS NULL 
RETURN n
```

Comment: @jjaderberg , ***tstorms*** thanks for the quick response. This node type has 65,247 members and I know that about 10% of them have no incoming relations. So, the correct code must return about 6500 nodes.  However, all the codes that I have tried, including those you sent me, return exactly 65,247 nodes!  I don't know how all the nodes are found in this query.  I changed your codes to:  `match (a:type_A)
OPTIONAL MATCH a <-[r:is_a]-(b:type_A)
WHERE r IS NULL 
RETURN count(distinct a)`
and  `match (a:type_A)
Where not ()-[:is_a]->a
RETURN count( distinct a)`  Any clues?  Best,

Comment: I edited the query, the WHERE is tied to the match, so it is applied _inside_ the match to filter match results you have to add a with afterwards

Answer (score 3):

Your first query will only match paths where there is a relationship `[r:is_a]`, so counting `r` can never be 0. Your second query will return any arbitrary pair of nodes labeled `:typeA` that aren't transitively related by `[:is_a]`. What you want is to filter on a path predicate. For the general case try

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE NOT ()-->a
```

This translates roughly "any node that does not have incoming relationships". You can specify the pattern with types, properties or labels as needed, for instance

```
MATCH (a:type_A)
WHERE NOT ()-[:is_a]->a
```

Comment: All the nodes are returned (with or without incoming relations). Any ideas?

Comment: If you run the first query and return `a`, any node returned has no incoming relationships. But you also qualify your pattern with things like "incoming relationships of type so-and-so" or "from node with label so-and-so", chances are something goes wrong there. Here is a [basic example](http://console.neo4j.org/r/vtbg4w) in the console, start there and try to reproduce the problem (you can add a small sample of your own data).